# Error with InitFont - OpenCV 3.1 (Python)

Tags: python, opencv3.1

I am working on OpenCV 3.1 and I would like to know how I can replace:

```
font = cv2.cv.InitFont(cv2.cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
```

in OpenCV 3.1 because this line generates the error "*module object has no attribute cv*" and even if I remove `cv` it generates the error "*module object has no attribute InitFont*".

Answer (score 5):

In my cat and human face identifier project, I have used the font like below:

**Python 3(OpenCV 3):**

```
import cv2
# font for the text written on image
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(img,"Cat",(x,y-10),font,0.55,(0,255,0),1)
```

Share your full code if you still have doubts.